# Whats the better approch for gold product pricing system in ecommerce site in mern development?

Tags: mongodb, express, next.js, e-commerce, mern

There are gold,diamand jewellry project in mern. there are long formula to price calculate, its vary on current gold rate ,weight and making charges majorly. its a ecommerce website what approch is best for showing product price .Currently we are saving price in product collection after apply formula. we are doing it every time while  updating gold rate,product. whats the best approch please suggest ?

I want that fetching data is smooth. and showing all products in filter page with calculated price. should i use socket for it or what ?

Answer (score 0):

while fetching products you should add your formula in api(node).so that all product should come with calculated price.